XML output from SQL Server based on header and details
I have these table values:



ID
MARKS
TOTALMARKS
SUBJECT
CODE




3789
15
40
Science
SC


3789
25
40
Math
M


3932
14
48
Science
SC


3932
34
48
Social
SO


3957
42
42
Math
M


4871
11
31
Eng
E


4871
20
31
Science
SC



I need the output in XML format, in the following way:
<REPORT>
    <DETAILS>
        <S_HEADER>
            <ID>3789</ID>
            <TOTALMARKS>40</TOTALMARKS>
        </S_HEADER>
        <S_DETAILS>
            <SUBJECT>Science</SUBJECT>
            <MARKS>15</MARKS>
            <CODE>SC</CODE>
        </S_DETAILS>
        <S_DETAILS>
            <SUBJECT>Maths</SUBJECT>
            <MARKS>25</MARKS>
            <CODE>M</CODE>
        </S_DETAILS>
    </DETAILS>
    <DETAILS>
        <S_HEADER>
            <ID>3932</ID>
            <TOTALMARKS>48</TOTALMARKS>
        </S_HEADER>
        <S_DETAILS>
            <SUBJECT>Science</SUBJECT>
            <MARKS>14</MARKS>
            <CODE>SC</CODE>
        </S_DETAILS>
        <S_DETAILS>
            <SUBJECT>Social</SUBJECT>
            <MARKS>34</MARKS>
            <CODE>SO</CODE>
        </S_DETAILS>
    </DETAILS>
    <DETAILS>
        <S_HEADER>
            <ID>3957</ID>
            <TOTALMARKS>42</TOTALMARKS>
        </S_HEADER>
        <S_DETAILS>
            <SUBJECT>Maths</SUBJECT>
            <MARKS>42</MARKS>
            <CODE>M</CODE>
        </S_DETAILS>
    </DETAILS>
    <DETAILS>
        <S_HEADER>
            <ID>4871</ID>
            <TOTALMARKS>31</TOTALMARKS>
        </S_HEADER>
        <S_DETAILS>
            <SUBJECT>eng</SUBJECT>
            <MARKS>11</MARKS>
            <CODE>E</CODE>
        </S_DETAILS>
        <S_DETAILS>
            <SUBJECT>science</SUBJECT>
            <MARKS>20</MARKS>
            <CODE>SC</CODE>
        </S_DETAILS>
    </DETAILS>
</REPORT>

Header contains the group values and individual details will comes under <Details> element.
I had tried with FOR XML PATH, but GROUP BY is causing an error.
SELECT(SELECT(
     SELECT
     ID
    ,TOTALMARKS

    FOR XML PATH('S_HEADER') ,type
    ),

    (
    SELECT
      SUBJECT
     ,MARKS
     ,CODE

     FOR XML PATH('S_DETAILS'),TYPE
    )  FROM TRACK   FOR XML PATH('DETAILS'),ROOT('REPORT'))AS xml_out

In the query i tried to use ORDER BY and Group by ...But giving error. Is there any way to achieve this?
Please help me with the SQL query needed to achieve this output.

Hi friend - if you've made some attempts, then it's best if you show details of what you've already attempted, including any specific error messages that you are receiving.  You get the most benefit from StackOverflow by working through your issues and hopefully resolving it yourself (with guidance from others) - rather than just having someone write the query for you

@DaleK ..Had updated accordingly .

A group by on Id and TotalMarks would be the way to start, with a subquery to return the S_DETAILS elements. What was the query you tried with that and what was the error message?

Code values in the XML don't match data sample

@AlwaysLearning Let me try with that option

total marks in your last row looks incorrect

It is possible when you combine FOR XML with PATH Mode, XPath as column names and nested FOR XML queries:
SELECT id AS [S_HEADER/ID], SUM(marks) AS [S_HEADER/TOTALMARKS], (
    SELECT subject AS [SUBJECT], marks AS [MARKS], code AS [CODE]
    FROM t AS x
    WHERE id = t.id
    FOR XML PATH('S_DETAILS'), TYPE
)
FROM t
GROUP BY id
FOR XML PATH('DETAILS'), ROOT('REPORT')

Result:
<REPORT>
  <DETAILS>
    <S_HEADER>
      <ID>3789</ID>
      <TOTALMARKS>40</TOTALMARKS>
    </S_HEADER>
    <S_DETAILS>
      <SUBJECT>Science</SUBJECT>
      <MARKS>15</MARKS>
      <CODE>SC</CODE>
    </S_DETAILS>
    <S_DETAILS>
      <SUBJECT>Math</SUBJECT>
      <MARKS>25</MARKS>
      <CODE>M</CODE>
    </S_DETAILS>
  </DETAILS>
  <DETAILS>
    <S_HEADER>
      <ID>3932</ID>
      <TOTALMARKS>48</TOTALMARKS>
    </S_HEADER>
    <S_DETAILS>
      <SUBJECT>Science</SUBJECT>
      <MARKS>14</MARKS>
      <CODE>SC</CODE>
    </S_DETAILS>
    <S_DETAILS>
      <SUBJECT>Social</SUBJECT>
      <MARKS>34</MARKS>
      <CODE>SO</CODE>
    </S_DETAILS>
  </DETAILS>
  <DETAILS>
    <S_HEADER>
      <ID>3957</ID>
      <TOTALMARKS>42</TOTALMARKS>
    </S_HEADER>
    <S_DETAILS>
      <SUBJECT>Math</SUBJECT>
      <MARKS>42</MARKS>
      <CODE>M</CODE>
    </S_DETAILS>
  </DETAILS>
  <DETAILS>
    <S_HEADER>
      <ID>4871</ID>
      <TOTALMARKS>31</TOTALMARKS>
    </S_HEADER>
    <S_DETAILS>
      <SUBJECT>Eng</SUBJECT>
      <MARKS>11</MARKS>
      <CODE>E</CODE>
    </S_DETAILS>
    <S_DETAILS>
      <SUBJECT>Science</SUBJECT>
      <MARKS>20</MARKS>
      <CODE>SC</CODE>
    </S_DETAILS>
  </DETAILS>
</REPORT>

DB<>Fiddle
